# React with Ruby on Rails assets precompiling

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I have run into a problem when my localhost server looks completely different than my remote. However, the code is the same and whenever I change something on the remote server, it will reflect on the page as well, therefore I am 100% sure I am using the same code.

[image: My Gemfile varies only in a database otherwise, it is the same]
My Gemfile varies only in a database otherwise, it is the same

My gemlist and I am using development on both servers

```
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'   
gem 'react-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]    
gem 'devise'
```

It seems that my remote server is using some old sort version of my React files but the files on local and remote are identical, therefore I suppose the only reason must be caching or something like that. I tried calling `assets:precompile` but it didn't work.

Is there a way how to precompile/reset caches of react files?

**EDIT:** I copied my local files (all of them, including tmp folder) to the remote server and it is working. But how can I do the same compilation on the remote without actually grabbing my tmp files from my local env?

Comment: You can delete the top level tmp folder where assets are cached

Comment: Tried that, didn't work

Comment: did the asset precompile give you any meaningful errors in production?

Comment: no, actually everything precompiles without errors. I just heard that you need to build react somehow. I am not using any webpacker or anything like that